# started to learn EJB. What options do I have for an application server?

Tags: ejb

I have started learning EJB. I like to know which is best application server for beginner to learn EJB...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend an open source server as there are plenty good ones available.  The open source servers often have greater community support which is helpful while learning.

- [Caucho Resin](http://www.caucho.com/) (also has a commercial extension)
- [Sun Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/)
- [JBoss Application Server](http://jboss.org/)

Comment: To expand this answer a bit more: Glassfish in its current release already supports the fresh new Java EE 6 API, while others are still at Java EE 5. It may take some months.

Answer (score 0):

I think JBoss Appliocation Server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the particular app server matters too much, the basic criterion is that it should support JEE5 (EJB3 and JPA) rather than being limited to earlier versions of those specs.

There are free app servers such as [WebSphere Community Edition](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/community/)(WCE) which is based in Apache Geronimo.

You will probably find it convenient to use a development tool such as Eclipse, check that whichever server you use is supported by some such tool. WCE has a suitable Eclipse [plugin](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/websphere/wasce/updates/)